# How to replicate django authentication in several services

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, authorization, soa

We have a web app using Django. We have the authentication system setup as described below. Now, we would like to take some part of the application to an independent service, but we would like to have the same valid token/authentication system. The new service will be using Django too, probably, so I would like to know if this is even possible or what options do I have to implement this behavior.

In the case that we do not use Django in the new service, there would be a way to still use the same logic to authenticate requests on the two services?

#### Authentication system

Right now, we are authenticating the requests using the `rest_framework` module, more precisely, the `TokenAuthentication` class.

This is the configuration:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
     ...
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    ...
}

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
    ),

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'module.authentications.AuthorizedAuthentication',
    )
}
```

And the code we use to authorize the requests:

```py
import logging
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.exceptions import AuthenticationFailed


class AuthorizedAuthentication(TokenAuthentication):

    def authenticate(self, request):
        response = TokenAuthentication.authenticate(self, request)
        if response is None:
            return None
        return response
```

To authenticate in the views, we do something like this:

```py
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.views import APIView


class SomeView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

**EDIT**

The code is not complete so please do not comment about it, I have just copied to show you a simplified example about our configuration.

Comment: What prevents you from copying this code to the new system? Do you want to have the same token working for both services?

Comment: BTW, what the point of `AuthorizedAuthentication` class? It's  `authenticate` method replicates (in some weird way) exactly `TokenAuthentication.authenticate` (which can also be called as `super().authenticate(request)` and is more correct), and the `_logger` is not used anywhere. You could just use `TokenAuthentication` class directly

Comment: Yeah, I want the same token everywhere, it’s written on the question. And I have not copied the full code in the question, so that class is not complete!

Comment: Okay, sorry, I wasn't sure so decided to double-check. I think you'll need to roll your own solution. Usually, it's done via some 3rd service that stores User info and handles the authentication tokens etc., and other services communicate with it to authorize and authenticate the user. The scheme is called Single Sign-On or SSO, there are many different solutions so you'll need to research and find what suits you. Alternatively you can make your first service an SSO provider and make requests from the 2nd to authenticate a user.

Comment: Mmm thanks! I had not thought about SSO. I have also thought about JWT, because I do not to store those in my database and I can validate them in different places with the same secret.

Comment: Yes JWT would work. You just need to make sure all your apps decode and validate the signature in the same way